# Can you get sued or charged criminally for financing a group seeking to secede from the U.S. government?

Tags: criminal-law, secession

Can you get sued or charged criminally for financing a group seeking to secede from the U.S. government? Let's say there's this group in Hawaii that wants to secede from the U.S. and you decide to finance them, can the U.S. government charge you criminally for doing so, or is it within the rights of any American citizen to do so?

Comment: Do they plan to secede by voting or by violence?

Comment: Is there a mechanism in the Constitution to secede by voting?

Comment: Alternatively secede by non-recognition of the authority of the Federal government as the first step of Texas secessionist movement is doing .

Comment: @DJohnM Well, a constitutional amendment could easily allow a state to secede.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Supporting a secessionist movement is protected by the First Amendment. Terrorism, in the name of a secessionist movement or otherwise, or support of terrorism is a federal offense. See [18 USC 2339A](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/2339A) and [2339B](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/2339B). The latter applies to foreign terrorist organizations, the former applies to to anything in violation of a specific list of crimes (§§32, 37, 81, 175, 229, 351, 831, 842(m) or (n), 844(f) or (i), 930(c), 956, 1091, 1114, 1116, 1203, 1361, 1362, 1363, 1366, 1751, 1992, 2155, 2156, 2280, 2281, 2332, 2332a, 2332b, 2332f, 2340A, 2442 of Title 18, and a few other things). Advocating secesion is not a crime, so supporting the advocacy of secession – in the US – is not a crime.

§2339B determines what terrorist-organization status via [18 USC 1189](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1189), which is basically a finding by the Secretary of State, in consultation with the Secretary of the Treasury and the Attorney General that "the organization threatens the security of United States nationals or the national security of the United States". [Here](https://www.state.gov/foreign-terrorist-organizations/) is a current list.

Advocating the forceful overthrow of the US government or that of any state or lower political subdivision is a crime under [18 USC 2385](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/2385), likewise
abetting, advising, or teaching the duty, necessity, desirability, or propriety of such overthrow.

Comment: That looks like like plainly unconstitutional provision. Has it ever been tested in court? What is the most recent case law?

Comment: @Obie2.0 the answer has several links, as well as some references without links. Is there a particular one that you think is unconstitutional and want to see relevant court rulings, or are you objecting to the general idea that treason is illegal?

Comment: @KamilDrakari - That is not from federal statutes on treason, and indeed, it does not mention treason at all. As you probably know, treason is a very narrow crime, which has, in all but one or two recent cases, been interpreted as only applying to people who aid groups that the US is at war with.

Comment: I am talking about the last link, which says that it is illegal to merely advocate (not conspire to carry out or arrange) the forceful overthrow of the US government through violence or assassination, which seems like it could certainly run into some issues with freedom of expression. Things that could fall (or could have fallen) into that category: Saying "someone should kill that lunatic Trump before he destroys the country" or arguing that "the proletariat need to rise up and overthrow the capitalist government," among other things.

Comment: Or under a broader but perhaps still plausible interpretation, any of various somewhat radical activist groups that say that the system must be overthrown, through violence if necessary, and talk about the US government being part of that system, but don't take it any further than rhetoric (or even if they do use violence, are not actually trying to overthrow the government). Of course, there are many such groups, with various goals.

Comment: @Obie2.0 I think that this falls under the reasoning of "[the Constitution is Not a Suicide Pact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Constitution_is_not_a_suicide_pact)"

Comment: @RBarryYoung - I hardly think the lack of such a law is suicidal. The strongest evidence of that is that, in fact, various people promote all the ideas that I mentioned every day without any legal consequence. That is, the law is not even enforced, and the nation is still here.... Plus, the fact that the three most recent examples given in the link are Donald Trump, someone justifying the "war on terrorism", and someone trying to strip people of their citizenship for not going to war definitely gives me pause about abuse of that concept.

Comment: @Obie2.0 Wikipedia indicates the current precedent was established in the case Brandenburg v. Ohio, which limits it to a fairly narrow application. Admittedly Wikipedia isn't the best source, but I didn't find anything more reliable that could be searched so easily.

Comment: @Obie2.0 No one here said that the *lack of a law* was.  Nor does the article I linked to say that.  What it says is that is that constitutional rights, including the freedom of speech does not compel the law or the courts to ignore violent threats to the nation, specifically including speech that advocates violence.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - Well, that is your school of legal thought, of course. Others might disagree—including, of course, the court in *Brandenburg v. Ohio*, when it established the imminent lawless action test and struck down the anti-syndicalism law on the basis that merely advocating violence was insufficient.

Comment: @Kamil - I know about that case, but definitely relevant. Did that case have to do with that specific provision of federal law mentioned in the answer, though?

Comment: @George - We are talking about 2385.